# How to handle list of lm objects or how to circumvent?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `APD` which consists of a factor (`Serial_number`) and each element of this factor has some observables (`Amplification` against `Voltage`). Now I would like to apply the function invest from the investr package to do an inverse regression across all serial numbers (means an inverse regression separated for each serial number).

This works very well if I only use the dataset of one Serial_number, e.g.:

```
> model<- lm(Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = APD[APD$Serial_number==608004648,])
> inverse<- invest(model, y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"),
       level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE
       )
> inverse
estimate    lower    upper 
385.4670 385.0665 385.8446
```

When I take the whole data frame:

```
> models<- dlply(APD, "Serial_number", function(df) lm(Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = df))
> inverse<- invest(models, y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"),
       level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE
       )
> Error in UseMethod("invest") : 
  no applicable method for 'invest' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I tried `inverse<- invest(models[1], y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none")` but it's the same problem.

I can't get my head around how to proceed further. I think this must be such a daily issue there are probably already practical solutions present. Don't they?

My next step would be to create a lm-object for each Serial_number but also this seems unnecessary complicated.

```
> model<- lm(Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = APD[APD$Serial_number==608004648,])
> str(model)
List of 12
 $ coefficients : Named num [1:3] 59714.045 -318.043 0.424
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
 $ residuals    : Named num [1:4] -0.0483 0.1458 -0.1459 0.0484
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ effects      : Named num [1:4] -295.61 -38.412 3.412 -0.217
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)" ""
 $ rank         : int 3
 $ fitted.values: Named num [1:4] 124 138 155 175
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
 $ assign       : int [1:3] 0 1 2
 $ qr           :List of 5
  ..$ qr   : num [1:4, 1:3] -2 0.5 0.5 0.5 -770 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:3] 0 1 2
  ..$ qraux: num [1:3] 1.5 1 1.37
  ..$ pivot: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  ..$ rank : int 3
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
 $ df.residual  : int 1
 $ xlevels      : Named list()
 $ call         : language lm(formula = Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = APD[APD$Serial_number == 608004648, ])
 $ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
 $ model        :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Amplification: num [1:4] 124 138 155 175
  ..$ Voltage      : num [1:4] 382 384 386 388
  ..$ I(Voltage^2) :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:4] 145900 147440 148975 150528
  ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
```

`str(models)` are hundreds of lines..  a few are:

```
models<- dlply(APD, "Serial_number", function(df) lm(Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = df))
str(models)
(...)
$ 713006445 :List of 12
  ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:3] 68847.991 -386.479 0.543
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:4] -0.0655 0.1964 -0.1962 0.0653
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ effects      : Named num [1:4] -317.503 45.226 4.347 0.293
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)" ""
  ..$ rank         : int 3
  ..$ fitted.values: Named num [1:4] 131 146 167 191
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ assign       : int [1:3] 0 1 2
  ..$ qr           :List of 5
  .. ..$ qr   : num [1:4, 1:3] -2 0.5 0.5 0.5 -730.1 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:3] 0 1 2
  .. ..$ qraux: num [1:3] 1.5 1 1.96
  .. ..$ pivot: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  .. ..$ rank : int 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..$ df.residual  : int 1
  ..$ xlevels      : Named list()
  ..$ call         : language lm(formula = Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = df)
  ..$ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0xb810100> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..$ model        :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ Amplification: num [1:4] 131 147 166 191
  .. ..$ Voltage      : num [1:4] 362 364 366 368
  .. ..$ I(Voltage^2) :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:4] 131064 132516 133974 135445
  .. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0xb810100> 
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ 713006446 :List of 12
  ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:3] 58059.34 -331.908 0.475
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..$ residuals    : Named num [1:4] -0.0574 0.1729 -0.1727 0.0573
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ effects      : Named num [1:4] -300.53 -41.391 3.808 -0.258
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)" ""
  ..$ rank         : int 3
  ..$ fitted.values: Named num [1:4] 124 139 158 180
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  ..$ assign       : int [1:3] 0 1 2
  ..$ qr           :List of 5
  .. ..$ qr   : num [1:4, 1:3] -2 0.5 0.5 0.5 -717.9 ...
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "4"
  .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "(Intercept)" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:3] 0 1 2
  .. ..$ qraux: num [1:3] 1.5 1 1.37
  .. ..$ pivot: int [1:3] 1 2 3
  .. ..$ tol  : num 1e-07
  .. ..$ rank : int 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "qr"
  ..$ df.residual  : int 1
  ..$ xlevels      : Named list()
  ..$ call         : language lm(formula = Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2), data = df)
  ..$ terms        :Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0xb6fc150> 
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..$ model        :'data.frame':   4 obs. of  3 variables:
  .. ..$ Amplification: num [1:4] 124 139 157 180
  .. ..$ Voltage      : num [1:4] 356 358 360 362
  .. ..$ I(Voltage^2) :Class 'AsIs'  num [1:4] 126715 128145 129576 131024
  .. ..- attr(*, "terms")=Classes 'terms', 'formula'  language Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "variables")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "factors")= int [1:3, 1:2] 0 1 0 0 0 1
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "term.labels")= chr [1:2] "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "order")= int [1:2] 1 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "intercept")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "response")= int 1
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: 0xb6fc150> 
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "predvars")= language list(Amplification, Voltage, I(Voltage^2))
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "dataClasses")= Named chr [1:3] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
  .. .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Amplification" "Voltage" "I(Voltage^2)"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "lm"
 $ 713006449 :List of 12
  ..$ coefficients : Named num [1:3] 56708.406 -324.219 0.464
(...)
```

I use RStudio/Ubuntu 14.04.

edit: Due to advices of joran and Gregor I tried the following:

```
> invest(models[[1]], y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"), level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE)
Error in invest.lm(models[[1]], y0 = 150, interval = c("inversion", "Wald",  : 
  'x0.name' is missing, please select a valid predictor variable
```

and

in case of lapply I'm not sure how to define it `> lapply(X, FUN, ...)` and in my case this would be `lapply(object, invest(object, ..))` :

```
> lapply(models, invest(models, y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"), level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE))
Error in UseMethod("invest") : 
  no applicable method for 'invest' applied to an object of class "list"
```

editedit:
I tried to use a lmList as follows:

```
library(nlme)
models<- lmList(Amplification ~ Voltage + I(Voltage^2)|Serial_number, data= APD)
> invest(models[[1]], y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"),
+        level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE)
Error in eval(object$call$data, envir = parent.frame()) : 
  object 'dat' not found
```

Has someone an idea how to proceed? I take every solution which allows to apply a lm fit to the factor of a dataset and then to apply the invest function to each lm object.
Isn't there the possibility to extract a lm object out of a list of lm objects and it remains as an lm object?

Comment: Can you provide at the very least the output of `str()` on the `model` object that generates the error? I don't really see why your first and second `lm` calls would generate different types of objects, so we're missing some information here.

Comment: Sure, one moment!

Comment: Ah. Your original version left out lots of pretty crucial information. I think this is actually very simple. You have a list of `lm` objects. `[` will return a _sub-list_. `[[` will return an _element_ of a list. You want `[[`, not `[`.

Comment: You can't pass a list of `lm` objects to `invest`. The documentation pretty clearly rules that out. But you already appear to know how to iterate over a list, so you could do that again. Or call `invest` one at a time, but be sure to use `models[[1]]`, not `models[1]`.

Comment: `lapply(models, invest, ...)`?

Comment: Thanks so far! When I apply "invest(models[[1]], ...)" I receive "x0.name' is missing, please select a valid predictor variable". This is the same as for lapply(models, invest,..).

Comment: @joran I assume models[[1]] does not work so can you please tell me how do I iterate over the list to apply invest to each lm object?

Comment: Your `lapply` syntax is bad - it is not `lapply(models, invest(...))`, it is `lapply(models, invest, ...)`. Something like `lapply(models, invest, y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"), level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE)`.

Comment: But the error seems clear: *`x0.name` is missing error.* Have you tried adding in a `x0.name` argument? It's described in the documentation as *"For multiple linear regression, a character string giving the the name of the predictor variable of interest"*.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Unfortunately, this results also in "Error in invest.lm(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'x0.name' is missing, please select a valid predictor variable".
When I add "x0=Voltage" the error "Error in invest.lm(X[[i]], ...) : 
  'newdata' must be supplied when multiple predictor variables exist!" occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else will have a hard time solving this "trivial" issue: I circumvented the scenario above by splitting the data frame into many data frames separated by the levels of the factor:

```
new_data_frame<- split(data_frame, data_frame$factor)
```

Next, I iterate through all data frames and fit and invest each:

```
for(i in 1:length(new_data_frame)){
  temp_data_frame<- as.data.frame(new_data_frame[i])
  fit<- lm(Response ~ Predictor, data = temp_model_frame)
  inverse_regression<- invest(fit, y0=150, interval=c("inversion", "Wald", "percentile", "none"), level=0.95, mean.response = FALSE)
  # some lines to store each time inverse_regression..
}
```